# Mock virtual methods and not mock overridden of this methods with Moq

Tags: unit-testing, moq, xunit

In the below code I want to mock DB operation of `GetTitle(int id)` in `FooBase` class. But I want to test validations part in overridden `GetTitle(int id)`.

**I want to test overridden method but mock the base method**

How I can mock virtual method and testing the overridden of it?

```cs
public abstract class FooBase
{
    public virtual string GetTitle(int id) { return "Title From DB" /*Select From DB*/; }
}

public class Foo : FooBase
{
    public override string GetTitle(int id)
    {
        if (id < 0)
            return "Invalid id";

        /*Doing somethings like other validations and etc*/

        return $"Valid ID ({base.GetTitle(id)})";
    }
}

public class FooTests
{
    [Fact]
    public void GetTitle() // Fails
    {
        // Arrange
        var expectedID = 1;
        var expectedResult = "Test";
        var fooMock = new Mock<Foo>();
        fooMock.Setup(x => x.GetTitle(It.IsAny<int>())).Returns(expectedResult);
        var foo = fooMock.Object;

        // Act
        var title = foo.GetTitle(expectedID);

        // Assert
        fooMock.Verify(x => x.GetTitle(It.Is<int>(c => expectedID == c)), Times.Once);
        Assert.Equal($"Valid ID ({expectedResult})", title);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is how inheritance works. Moq creates an inheritor of `Foo` dynamically (called a proxy) and so it has its own implementation of `GetTitle` entirely that you can either tell to call its own base or give some custom behavior through the means that Moq provides you, which are "return some value" or "throw some exception". You **cannot** mock out base implementation from an arbitrary class up the inheritance chain. I'm sorry to say that overall you are on an completely wrong path here, design-wise.

Comment: @MarioDS What would be the right design here?

Answer (score 6):

If you can separate your logic into a different method (what might be a better design too), than you can use Moq's `CallBase` property to make the test call the mocked method.

```cs
public abstract class FooBase
{
   public virtual string GetTitle(int id) { return "Title From DB" /*Select From DB*/; }
}

public class Foo : FooBase
{
  public virtual string GetValidatedTitle(int id)
  {
    if (id < 0)
    return "Invalid id";

    /*Doing somethings like other validations and etc*/

    return $"Valid ID ({GetTitle(id)})";
  }
}

public class FooTests
{
  [Fact]
  public void GetTitle() // Now Passes
  {
    // Arrange
    var expectedID = 1;
    var expectedResult = "Test";
    var fooMock = new Mock<Foo>() { CallBase = true };
    fooMock.Setup(x => x.GetTitle(It.IsAny<int>())).Returns(expectedResult);
    var foo = fooMock.Object;

    // Act
    var title = foo.GetValidatedTitle(expectedID);

    // Assert
    fooMock.Verify(x => x.GetTitle(It.Is<int>(c => expectedID == c)), Times.Once);
    Assert.Equal($"Valid ID ({expectedResult})", title);
  }
}
```